# SecItemAdd with SecIdentityRef

Tags: objective-c, reference, attributes, keychain

So I am sucessfully adding a SecIdentityRef to the keychain using SecItemAdd(); My problem is that the second parameter for SecItemAdd the result is not being set. Here are the parameters I am passing in:

```
{
     kSecAttrLabel = "Name";
     kSecAttrAccessible = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked;
     kSecReturnAttributes = 1;
     kSecReturnPersistentRef = 1;
     kSecReturnRef = 1;
     kSecValueRef = "<SecIdentityRef: 0x15617a70>";
}
```

I would like to hold a reference to the attributes and identity.